# Links saving separately from other data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am trying to save data from a website into mysql database. I was able to save most of all I wanted to save but I have a particular problem. The links I extracted are saving but I want the links to be in same lines other attributes.Below is my CURL and mysql query for extracting and saving the information into the database.

```
$target_url = "http://www.ucc.ie/modules/descriptions/BM.html";
$codeS = "BM";
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.ucc.ie/modules/descriptions/BM.html"); 
@$doc = new DomDocument(); 
@$doc->loadHtml($html); 
//discard white space   
@$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

//Read through dd tags
$options = $doc->getElementsByTagName('dd');

//Go into dd tags and look for all the links with class modnav 
$links = $xpath->query('//dd //a[@class = "modnav"]'); 

//Loop through and display the results for links
foreach($links as $link){    
echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br><br>';
}   

foreach ($options as $option) { 

    $option->nodeValue;
    echo "Node Value (Module name/title)= $option->nodeValue <br /><br /> <br />"; 

      // save both for each results into database
$query3 = sprintf("INSERT INTO all_modulenames(code,module_name,description_link,gathered_from) 
     VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
     mysql_real_escape_string ($codeS),
     mysql_real_escape_string($option->nodeValue),
     mysql_real_escape_string($link->getAttribute('href')),
     mysql_real_escape_string($target_url));
     mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error()."<br />".$query3); 

    } 
    echo "<br /> <br /> <br />";


Here is the table
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `all_modulenames`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `all_modulenames`;
CREATE TABLE `all_modulenames_copy` (
`code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`module_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`gathered_from` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of all_modulenames
-- ----------------------------
```

So the issue is the "$link->getAttribute('href')" are saving separately from other content am trying to save.The links are saved first and then followed by the rest of the data leaving some rows empty but am trying to save everything all at once i.e fill each row and them move to the second row until the for each statement finish. How could I do this please ? Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: the query should be inside a loop

Comment: there's also an extra dollar sign `mysql_real_escape_string($$link->getAttribute('href')),` which doesn't seem intentional. This would most likely cause that field to be blank.

Comment: Hey thanks I have the query in the loop and I still get thesame result. 
@Sean Johnson and I corrected that mistake of $$ and still thesame result am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested (so will need debugging) but I would approach something like this:

```
...etc
@$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;  

//Read through dd tags 
$options = $doc->getElementsByTagName('dd'); 

foreach ($options as $option) {  

    // Get the links and find the one with the right class
    $href = '';
    $links = $option->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($link as $link) {
        if ($link->hasAttribute('class') && $link->hasAttribute('href')) {
            $aClasses = explode(' ', $link->getAttribute('class'));
            if (in_array('modnav', $aClasses)) {
                  $href=$link->getAttribute('href');
            }
        }
    }

    Insert in to SQL etc, $href is the link text belonging to the dd ...
```

Comment: Hi Robbie,thanks for the repply.I tried using the above code but I got the error : **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'** . This error is realted to this line: `$aClasses = explode(' ', );` .Any suggestion on solving this please?

Comment: Fixed that line. You may get other errors and also need to debug - sorry if you do but it's just an untested suggestion (based on the fact no-one else is answering). NOTE: I've also edited the line $href=$link->getAttribute('href'); as that was wrong

Comment: Hey Robbie,thanks alot for fixing the error.I also fixed the foreach statement.The 2 variables have thesame name and also added another closing bracket to the end of the code.Really appreciate your time and effort,I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on with it.Thanks